# jQuery - Add Arrow to jquery.firstVisitPopup.js popup

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, popup

I am using jQuery First Visit Popup (https://www.jqueryscript.net/lightbox/jQuery-Plugin-To-Show-A-Popup-Only-Once-Per-Visitor-First-Visit-Popup.html) to add a popup to a web page the first time someone visits it. It works fine. It's just a square box with a message. Click the X and it goes away, click a link and it comes back. Very nice. But I want to be able to add an arrow to the box, pointing down from the bottom right hand side.

I found "Add arrow in tooltip with CSS", here, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/add-arrow-in-tooltip-with-css. I have tried but failed to use that code to alter the First Visit Popup.
Here is the CSS I use.

```
#fvpp-blackout {
  display: none;
  z-index: 199;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#my-welcome-message {
  display: none;
  z-index: 500;
  position: fixed;
  width: 20%
  left: 20%;
  top: 60%;
  padding: 20px 2%;
  font-family: Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
  background: #282467;
  border-radius: 6px;
  color: green;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #0003;
}

#fvpp-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#fvpp-dialog q {
  font: 12px trebuchet ms,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
  color:#ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin:0px;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

and in the javascript and html is

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.firstVisitPopup.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$('#my-welcome-message').firstVisitPopup({
  cookieName : 'homepage',
  showAgainSelector: '#show-message'
});
</script>


<div id="my-welcome-message" >
  <h1>My Message</h1>
  <h1>Hover over the colored dots for more information.</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're using bootstrap you can use the tooltip class (search "arrow" on this page) https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/

If not I have found a way to do this is to put the arrow in a div as a unicode triangle (you can use up, down, left, right etc.)

Adapted from this article written in 2012 https://css-tricks.com/triangle-with-shadow/ . When the article was written, filters weren't a thing yet.

```css
#overall {
  filter: drop-shadow(8px 8px 10px gray);
}

#arrow {
  padding-left: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: scaleX(1.5);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#blah {
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: -10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div id="overall">
  <div id="arrow">
    ▲
  </div>
  <div id="blah">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Justo eget magna fermentum iaculis eu non. Elementum integer enim neque volutpat. In iaculis nunc sed augue. Non arcu risus quis varius quam quisque. Leo a diam sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl nunc mi. Accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat est. Suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor. Aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a scelerisque. Velit scelerisque in dictum non consectetur. Sit amet justo donec enim diam. Pretium aenean pharetra magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus mauris.
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a code pen you can use as a template as well https://codepen.io/holmesrg/pen/BaRMGRq

Comment: Thanks very much, I was able to get what I wanted there.